# how to use macro #define to change class name?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a `class`

```
 class A{}
```

But I want to use macro to replace the class name A with the following statement:

```
#define SOMETHING A
```

The definition of `class A {}` is in the same .cpp with the MACRO.

Does it correct?

I want to do this, because I am removing all of the MACRO in the source code. But the MACRO was used widely. Does any software could help me to do the replacement of MACRO ?

Comment: Why do you want to do something that is preposterous?

Comment: Please, for your own good: Keep usage of macros to a minimum.

Comment: ... And for your own sanity

Comment: Concerning your edit: On linux platforms you can use `grep "BAD_MACRO_NAME" file1 ./path/to/file2` to search for all uses of the macro, but beware of any place in which the name is used in a different context!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the tokens; `#define A SOMETHING` should work.

Note that it is a terrible idea as it may break other code and confuse the hell out of people.

Use an alias instead:

```
class A { … };
using SOMETHING = A;
```

Comment: why does the oder is #define A SOMETHING.  I konw #define N 50. it will use 50 to replace "N" in the code. So I understand it will use the second one to replace the first one. Could you help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2701639 Yes, all instances (match of first token) (where the macro is visible) will be replaced by the value of the macro (second thing).

Comment: if so, why you use #define A SOMETHING not #define SOMETHING A ?

Comment: You said you wanted to replace the class name.

Comment: please forgave me I have just asked a very stupid question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try `#define A SOMETHING`. Then, if the preprocessor sees `public class A`, it will presumably replace your class name to give `public class SOMETHING`. Why in the world would you ever want to do such a thing though?

Comment: > Why in the world would you ever want to do such a thing though?

- Well, life is full wonderful moments. Sometimes you may wish to replace some class in the middle of a huge hierarchy, but without touching the codebase (which is not yours!) and make it compile together with the original code...  Couple of #define statements like that can do magic :)